# Convert/Reshape 3D Matrix to a 2D Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a 3D matrix `X` which contains vectors as rows into the 3rd dimension. I would like to extract each such vector `X(:, x, y)` and save it as a 2D matrix such that `X(:, 0, 0)` is the first row of the 2D matrix, `X(:, 0, 1)` the second, and so on. The following crude graphic might help illustrate this:

[image: Crude Sketch]

I know that I can create my new 2D matrix and then iterate over the original `X` to add the vectors, but does somebody have some input on how to do this quick and efficiently?

---

Example: Given

```
>>> a = np.arange(9*3).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

I would like to get the following as rows, though the order of the rows does not matter:

```
array([[ 0,  9, 18],
       [ 1, 10, 19]],
       ...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) and then [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) like so -

```
X.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,X.shape[0])
```

Explanation -

1) You want to get rows formed off `X[:, 0, 0]`, `X[:, 0, 1]`, etc., i.e., we have to "push" the `axis=0` elements to the last axis of such a 2D array output. Next up, we have to decided the order of rows, which would be formed out of `axes=1,2` from it. Now, going back to the desired 2D array output, between the first and second rows, i.e. between `X[:, 0, 0]` and `X[:, 0, 1]`, `axis=1` stays the same. So, in the 2D array output, the second axis (axis=1) would have precedence over the third axis (axis=2). So, in `X` we push `axis=1` to `axis=0` and `axis=2` to `axis=1`. Since, as stated earlier `axis=0` in `X` had to be moved to the last axis, so that would be `axis=2`. All of this could be done with `X.transpose(1,2,0)`. Let's call it `Y` .

2) Finally, we have to reshape `Y` to a `2D` array such that the number of elements in each row is same as `X.shape[0]`, which is achieved through `Y.reshape(-1,X.shape[0])`. Thus, the final solution becomes -

```
X.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,X.shape[0])
```

Sample run -

```
In [25]: X
Out[25]: 
array([[[ 0.19508052,  0.02481975],
        [ 0.88915956,  0.95974095]],

       [[ 0.23271151,  0.14730822],
        [ 0.56763563,  0.30607283]],

       [[ 0.33259228,  0.42552102],
        [ 0.28950926,  0.47782175]]])

In [26]: X[:, 0, 0]
Out[26]: array([ 0.19508052,  0.23271151,  0.33259228])

In [27]: X[:, 0, 1]
Out[27]: array([ 0.02481975,  0.14730822,  0.42552102])

In [28]: X[:, 1, 0]
Out[28]: array([ 0.88915956,  0.56763563,  0.28950926])

In [29]: X[:, 1, 1]
Out[29]: array([ 0.95974095,  0.30607283,  0.47782175])

In [30]: X.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,X.shape[0])
Out[30]: 
array([[ 0.19508052,  0.23271151,  0.33259228],
       [ 0.02481975,  0.14730822,  0.42552102],
       [ 0.88915956,  0.56763563,  0.28950926],
       [ 0.95974095,  0.30607283,  0.47782175]])
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion! the order of the rows does not really matter for my application, either is fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes sense!

Comment: @Divakar How could we make `X.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,X.shape[0])` work for any array of `X` with larger column?

Comment: @wondim This should work for array with any generic number of columns.

Comment: It is just creating three columns only even though the input is 4.

Comment: @wondim Think it would make more sense if you could post a new question with [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok I will @Divakar